# R regex to match beginning and end of string, ignoring middle

Tags: r, regex

In R, how can I create the regex that matches beginning and end strings, ignoring everything between?

Specifically, how can I grep out of the following, the strings that begin with "./xl/worksheets" and end with ".xml"?

```
myfiles <- c("./_rels/.rels", "./xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels", 
"./xl/workbook.xml", "./xl/worksheets/sheet4.xml", 
"./xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet1.xml.rels", "./xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml", 
"./xl/printerSettings/printerSettings11.bin")
```

I succeed with

```
grep("^\\./xl/worksheets", myfiles) # returns 4 5 6
grep("\\.xml$", myfiles) # returns 3 4 6
```

And of course I can do this:

```
which(grepl("^\\./xl/worksheets", myfiles) &
  grepl("\\.xml$", myfiles)) # returns 4 6
```

But, I can't figure how to make the wildcard between two patterns.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply adding a match all pattern `.*` between the start and end should work:

```
grep("^\\./xl/worksheets.*\\.xml$", myfiles) 
# [1] 4 6
```